# ssh configuration without being asked for password

Tags: ssh, ssh-config

The goal, here, is to be able to only write `ssh 10.0.200.9.switch -l customer` from my laptop and be logged in without being asked for password.

- Switch is located inside local LAN meaning `Laptop --> bastion.example.com --> 10.0.200.9`.
- The switch does not support ssh keys, only password.
- Both my laptop and bastion server is running OpenSSH 7.2p2.
- Am using sshpass 1.05 when trying to skip password prompt. Am open for other solutions if it exist any.

This is semi working:

```
/home/user/.ssh/config configuration 1

Host bastion
    hostname bastion.example.com
    port 2222
    user root
    identityfile /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa

Match host *.switch user customer
    ProxyCommand ssh bastion -W $(echo %h | grep -Po '^[0-9.]+[0-9]+' ):%p
```

Working but asks for password

```
user@laptop:~/.ssh$ ssh 10.0.200.9.switch -l customer
customer@10.0.200.9.switch's password: 

Type 'help' or '?' to get help.
Switch#
```

Working and does not asks for password but is longer to write in console

```
user@laptop:~/.ssh$ export SSHPASS=secretPassWord
user@laptop:~/.ssh$ sshpass -e ssh 10.0.200.9.switch -l customer

Type 'help' or '?' to get help.
Switch
```

This is not working:

```
/home/user/.ssh/config configuration 2

Host bastion
    hostname bastion.example.com
    port 2222
    user root
    identityfile /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa

Match host *.switch user customer
    ProxyCommand sshpass -e ssh bastion -W $(echo %h | grep -Po '^[0-9.]+[0-9]+' ):%p
```

Changes in `.ssh/config file` does not have any effect

```
user@laptop:~/.ssh$ export SSHPASS=secretPassWord
user@laptop:~/.ssh$ ssh 10.0.200.9.switch -l customer
customer@10.0.200.9.switch's password:
```

Comment: As seen in my examples `$(..))` works fine.

Comment: Okay, I missed that looking at the failing case.

Answer (score 1):

I think in your configuration the `sshpass` in the ProxyCommand tries to give the password to the SSH connection going to `bastion`, not to the one finally going to the switch. Putting the `sshpass` *outside* the outer `ssh` ProxyCommand seems to work:

```
laptop$ export SSHPASS=sshhhh    
laptop$ sshpass -e ssh -o'Proxycommand ssh customer@bastion -W final.target.switch:22' blah@blah
```

Since `sshpass` puts the SSH client in a separate tty to fool it into accepting the password from itself, it would seem that `sshpass` must be ran before the SSH client. So having `ssh` run `sshpass` from `ssh/config` likely won't work.

But it should be doable to make a script to run `sshpass` and `ssh` with any needed options. This works for me, with the necessary configuration set in `~/.ssh/config`, as you had:

```
#/bin/bash
if [ -z "$1" ] ; then echo "usage: $0 <args...>" ; exit 1 ; fi
sshpass -e ssh "$@"
```

You can set the user to log in to in `.ssh/config`, too, so might be able to do without `-l`. Also, it seems `sshpass` doesn't deal well with `ssh` asking about unknown host keys, so setting up `known_hosts` beforehand (or using `StrictHostKeyChecking no`) may be necessary.

Comment: As you are saying, sshpass is probably giving the password to the bastion machine and not the switch. Please note that `sshpass -e ssh 10.0.200.9.switch -l customer` works in configuration 1 but is longer to write. How can I implement your suggestion into to .ssh/config file so I only need to type `ssh 10.0.200.9.switch -l customer`?

Comment: @NiklasHagman, you could make a shell script to do that, though you can't call it `ssh` then, without fixing logic in the script to know when to use `sshpass` and when not to.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use plink from the putty-tools. see: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html
Beside the fact that you can do a "plink -pw  ..." you can use the "-m " option for remote scripting.

Comment: Thank you for the alternative suggestion. Problem is that it is to far away from my goal to be able to only write `ssh 10.0.200.9.switch -l customer` in a console. And I do not use Windows :-)

Comment: There is "0.67 release source code for Unix" also available. And:
 Do a  "apt search putty"
if you use Ubuntu 16. I did not check other distros. There would be a way with scripting to meet you needs to wrap all this using ssh or putty at the same time, depending on command-options. But this would require more or less work...